# Log Loss normalization and sample weights in base R? Like sklearn.metrics.log_loss()

Tags: r, scikit-learn, loss-function

Is there a base R method for computing the log loss / cross-entropy loss with normalization and sample weights as indicated on the Sci Kit learn webpage? https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.log_loss.html

The use of mean() in [this base R log loss function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38282377/how-to-compute-log-loss-in-machine-learning) could be all that is needed for normalization. Sample weights might be simply multiplied by the arguments of that log loss function. I hope to research soon.

```
### Correct formula in native R 
logLoss2 <- function(pred, actual){
  -mean(actual * log(pred) + (1 - actual) * log(1 - pred))
}
logLoss2(actual = model$y, pred = model$fitted.values)
```